# Form not saving field updates

Tags: list, workflow

I have a form that is regularly losing changes when I update fields and submit. I have seen this in very rare instances in the same (SP 2013) farm, but this is happening about 40% of the time. I suspect that it might be related to a pause I have set up in the workflow tied to this list, but I have pauses in other workflows (on different sites, but same farm) that don't cause this behavior. Beyond that, I am pretty stumped. Just tried republishing the form and got the same thing happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug with rich text fields in Mac OS Firefox. I didn't realize that rich text wasn't supported in any browser besides IE. Anyway, it was always the last field updated, so I figure something wasn't registering with the rich text field and not saving. I'm not positive, because I replaced all the rich text fields with plain text and haven't gotten the error in a dozen or so tests.